# Send email using phpMailer to multiple recipient from database using checkbox to selected email address(es)

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, phpmailer

I'm currently working on a php mysql base system that will send email to multiple recipients from database with checkbox functionally.

How can i send email to those recipient using check all functionality?

Here is my phpMailer code and is working fine

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
include("class.smtp.php");
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->IsSMTP();
$mailer->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465';
$mailer->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mailer->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mailer->Password = 'mypassword';
$mailer->From = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mailer->FromName = 'Admin';
$mailer->Body = 'TEST EMAIL';
$mailer->Subject = 'This is the subject of the email';
$mailer->AddAddress('myrecipient@yahoo.com');
if(!$mailer->Send())
{
echo "Message was not sent<br/ >";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mailer->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
 echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

another example code i'm currently using in the system to delete a user from database with checkbox functionality:

```
<?php
/*Check Box Commands*/
$id=$row_notification['user_id'];

if(isset($_POST['Delete'])) {
$checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
mysql_select_db($database_connection_ched, $connection_ched);
$id=$row_notification['user_id'];

for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++)
        {
            $delete = "DELETE FROM tb_user WHERE user_id=$checkbox[$i]";
            mysql_query($delete,$connection_ched);
        }
$result2 = mysql_query($delete);

    if($result2)
    {
    echo "<script language='javascript'>alert ('Successfully Deleted');</script>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=notification.php?\">";   }
}
/*End of Checkbox Commands*/
?>
```

Comment: If you're able to retrieve the list of email addresses to display in a checkbox list, then you've already got pretty much everything you need. The form submits back the ids (or whatever) of the selected email addresses, and you send the mail to them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some of your logic from the delete code you have there, but you can improve that too by just making one call to the db to get your info:

```
<?php
require("class.phpmailer.php");
include("class.smtp.php");
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->IsSMTP();
$mailer->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465';
$mailer->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mailer->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mailer->Password = 'mypassword';
$mailer->From = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$mailer->FromName = 'Admin';
$mailer->Body = 'TEST EMAIL';
$mailer->Subject = 'This is the subject of the email';

// get checkbox ids posted to us
$checkbox_ids = $_POST["checkbox"];

// get email addresses from db based on checkboxes posted to us
$query = "select email from tb_user where user_id in(".join(",",$checkbox_ids).")";

// connect to db and run query
mysql_select_db($database_connection_ched, $connection_ched);
$result = mysql_query($query);
while( $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
    // make SURE we are not sending this to each and every recipient incrementally.
    // alternately, you can use $mailer->ClearAllRecipients(); <-- this will clear cc and bcc as well
    $mailer->ClearAddresses();
    // send it to THIS user...
    $mailer->AddAddress($data["email"]);


    print ($mailer->Send()) ? "Message sent to: " : "Message <b>not</b> sent to: ";
    print $data["email"]."<br />\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: An additional question.
How can i merge those two objects (mailer and delete function), so that i can call both functions in one button. Like if i click delete or other function like activation (with similar logic of delete) it will also send email to the recipient?

Comment: You could pass along the name of the button clicked (eg. "mail" or "delete") and check that value before you continue to the action.

OR

You could use another checkbox called "delete" that you would check for the existence of in you $_POST array before taking action on that user.